# Qualcomm Atheros wifi range issues

Tags: networking, lenovo, atheros

I have a Lenovo laptop with a qualcomm atheros device which is having some range issues. It works perfectly when very close to the router, but slows to a crawl or even completely disconnects when I get more than 10 feet away. I have run the wireless info script and pasted the results here:

http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/23295177/

What should I do to fix this? Thanks for the help!

Comment: In terminal, does a `sudo iwconfig wlp2s0 power off` help any? Cheers, Al

Comment: Are there any clues in the log? `dmesg | grep ath`

Comment: @heynnema I do use that but the problem still persists.

Comment: @chili555 Running that command gives me a lot of `no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!` Could this be causing the problem?

Comment: You probably just typed @chili555 commands incorrectly. The character in between dmesg and grep is a shift \. Cheers, Al

Comment: It will be much easier to evaluate the output if you paste it and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: @chili555 I have pasted the results to the command here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23306454/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest, as a start, that you update the firmware. From the terminal:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.161_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

Reboot and test. If this is ineffective, then check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit.

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Next, I'd set IPv6 to Ignore in Network Manager: http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/Installation_Guide/images/netconfig/network-connections-ipv6-ignore.png  This example is for ethernet, but you want wireless.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not very effective. What other things should I try?

Comment: Please see my edit above.